# Spotify apps dead after update?

Tags: spotify

I was developing a Spotify apps and all of the sudden Spotify restarted and updated.
Yey, great.. I got version 0.8.3.222.g317ab79d... however typing spotify:app:the_app_name doesnt work anymore. I get metadataFailed, sorry I could not find this app.

Anyone knows where I can find a downgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spotify 0.8.3 changed the app lookup slightly. The URI for getting at apps in development is now `spotify:app:application-identifier-in-manifest`.

This changes the behaviour in old versions, which used the application's directory name to load applications. It's also worth noting that your application must have a valid identifier and version in its `manifest.json` file. Remember to restart the client when changing your manifest so it notices the changes!

The keys you need to set are `BundleIdentifier` (which will be used to find the app) and `BundleVersion`. Documentation on the keys can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/#applicationmanifest).

Comment: Something to note, in order for Spotify to load a local version of the app the BundleVersion needs to be a number higher than the number in production or it could be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

When you check spotify.com you can see there is a be right back message this indicated either server or application failures just hold for a few minutes/hours and return to developing after message is gone.

Comment: I really do not think it has anything to do with a new version (why would you develop something only working for old versions?) just try the new one now since the servers are back up ;)