# Spotify app broken after update?

Tags: spotify

In regards to the following post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421944/1373154

will this be required with every application call? for example:

old script:

window.location = 'spotify:app:application:navTop';

new script:
window.location = 'spotify:app:application:bundleversion:navTop';

Curious if anyone knows how the change will effect scripting such as the example above

Answer (score 0):

You misread the post — you only need to replace the folder name with the Bundle Identifier in the URL:

`window.location = 'spotify:app:application-identifier:navTop';`

However, a version needs to be present in the manifest file for the application to be loaded. It doesn't need to be specified in the URL.