# Spotify appNotFound on OS X 10.8, Developer menu enabled

Tags: macos, apache, spotify, osx-mountain-lion

spotify:app:tutorial shows metadatafailed, error appNotFound
I have the develop menu. the folder is in ~/Spotify/tutorial
I've restarted spotify, reinstalled spotify. 
Now i'm thinking it has something to do with mountain lion. 
Anyone else running 10.8 and not having this issue?

I also have dnsmasq + apache running with .build & .dev tld setup in /etc/resolvers.
does anyone know if spotify is setting up a mini webserver for local development?

I figured I'd ask before dismantling my development stack

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5FSe.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 0.8.3 you have to add BundleIdentifier in your manifest. The tutorial does not have this (will be updated) and therefore, the app is not loaded.

Also note that the directory name becomes irrelevant, the app is now always found based on the identifier.

Comment: Detailed information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416228/spotify-apps-dead-after-update