# Spotify appNotFound

Tags: json, spotify

I'm trying to follow the Spotify app develop tutorial. I've follwed every step it says but the program keeps throwing the following error message: "metadataFailed - appNotFound". I've tryed everything with the manifest file, but it doesn't seems to help... I'm in Windows 7 and using Spotify v.0.8.3.222.g317ab79d

Any idea anybody? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `BundleVersion` and `BundleIdentifier` keys to the `manifest.json` file. The Tutorial will be updated soon.

More information here: [Spotify apps dead after update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416228/spotify-apps-dead-after-update)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I was updating my app to api 1.x.x. I noticed that `Dependencies` has to be at the **bottom** in your `mainfest`.

```
{
"BundleType": "Application",
"BundleVersion": "0.1.0",
"UserInstallable": false,
"SupportedLanguages": [
    "en"
],
"AppIcon": {
    "36x18": "tutorial.png"
},
"AppName": {
    "en": "Views Tutorial"
},
"BundleIdentifier" : "views-tutorial",
"VendorIdentifier" : "com.spotify",
"Dependencies": {
    "api": "1.0.0",
    "views": "1.0.0"
}
}
```