# Can't develop apps on latest Spotify build

Tags: spotify

I've been developing a Spotify app for a while but a new version came out that doesn't allow for app development (can't find the local app anymore).
I reverted back to the older build that used to be available on the Previews section of Spotify but every time I restart Spotify it re-installs the latest version.
Is there a way to either prevent the auto update or get a newer build that one can develop on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spotify apps dead after update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416228/spotify-apps-dead-after-update)

Answer (score 0):

The bundle loading logic changed with Spotify 0.8.3. Just search for the Spotify tag on Stack Overflow and you'll find many, many duplicates of your question.

This one has the answer you're looking for: [Spotify apps dead after update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416228/spotify-apps-dead-after-update)

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Would've been nice if they reflected those changes on their site.